# Solving an inequality : $n \geq 3$ , $n^{n} \lt (n!)^{2}$.

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, factorial

I proved this inequality in the following way:

Lemma: $r \in \Bbb N, r \geq 3$. We have $r^r \gt (r+1)^{r-1}$. 
 Proof: We apply the AM-GM inequality to the $r$ positive integers where there are $r-1$ $(r+1)$'s and one $1$. We obtain $$\frac {1+(r-1)(r+1)}{r} \gt  ((r+1)^{r-1})^{\frac {1}{r}}$$ wherefrom we get (since the $r^{{\rm th}}$ power function is increasing), $r^{r} \gt (r+1)^{r-1}$.

Now, I used mathematical induction to prove the statement. We have from the lemma, $(k!)^{2} \gt k^k \implies (k!)^{2} \gt (k+1)^{k-1}$ and multiplying this inequality by $(k+1)^{2}$, we have $((k+1)!)^{2} \gt (k+1)^{k+1}$ and obviously $(3!)^{2} \gt 3^3$.

Is there any direct proof of the statement that does not use induction and calculus?

Comment: See also [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: Well, Stirling's approximation with the upper bound on the error from the quadrature formula to ensure it starts working at n=3.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640602/show-that-if-n2-then-n2nn) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/640602)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint : $$n \le r(n-r+1)$$

Now take the product for $r=1$ to $r=n$.

Comment: Ah... I see $(n-r)(r-1) \geq 0$. I should have seen this before.