# How can I prove this by mathematical induction

Tags: induction

$n!>n^{n/2}$. For every positive integer greater than $2$

Comment: How much do you know about mathematical induction? Can you prove the basis, for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove this inequality with factorials: $n!>n^{\frac {n}{2}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339036/how-to-prove-this-inequality-with-factorials-nn-frac-n2)

Answer (score 4):

Start with $$n^{\frac{n}{2}} <n!$$ multiply by $n+1$ to get 
$$(n+1)n^{\frac{n}{2}} <(n+1)!$$

we now would like to show that

$$(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \leq (n+1)n^{\frac{n}{2}} $$
If we square this and rearrange we get

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq n+1$$
However $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq e<3$ is well known.